# How to get lists of X and Y from a list of points using a single linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I'm generating `List<int> x` and `List<int> y` from `List<Point> p` using this code:

```
List<int> x = (from a in p select a.X).ToList();
List<int> y = (from a in p select a.Y).ToList();
```

So is there any single LINQ query for getting `x` and `y` from `p`?

Comment: In your example the two lists are assigned to two different variables. Are you asking if that's possible in a single query, or are you asking if you can generate a single list with both the X and Y values?

Comment: If the former, no you cannot.  If the later, just `select a`.

Comment: You could return a Tuple<List<Int>, List<int>> from your query

Comment: I dont see the `Point` ;p (pun intended)

Comment: Ok, I don't think a tuple of lists work, but for each should work in every situation.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @leppie:`System.Drawing.Point`!

Comment: @Fuex:I want to create `x` and `y` using single linq query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No but you can do something like this:

```
var tuples = p.Select(x => new Tuple<int, int>(x.X, x.Y)).ToList();
```

But i think that the best solution remains this, using two queries:

```
List<int> x = (from a in p select a.X).ToList();
List<int> y = (from a in p select a.Y).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically can't, but you can fool yourself:

```
public static class LinqEx
{
    public static void ToLists<T, T1, T2>(this IEnumerable<T> source, SelectorDst<T, T1> selectorDst1, SelectorDst<T, T2> selectorDst2)
    {
        selectorDst1.List.AddRange(source.Select(selectorDst1.Selector));
        selectorDst2.List.AddRange(source.Select(selectorDst2.Selector));
    }
}

public class SelectorDst<T, TList>
{
    public readonly List<TList> List;
    public readonly Func<T, TList> Selector;

    public SelectorDst(List<TList> list, Func<T, TList> selector)
    {
        this.List = list;
        this.Selector = selector;
    }
}

... Some place in the code

var points = new List<Point>();
var xs = new List<int>();
var ys = new List<int>();

points.ToLists(new SelectorDst<Point, int>(xs, p => p.X),
               new SelectorDst<Point, int>(ys, p => p.Y));
```